# react-native android linking viro-react

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have installed the `viro` package and next thing is to link the package the problem is that I can't find the `android/build.gradle` or other files `android/app` `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper`
so what is wrong with it did I install the package wrong? because I downgrade the `react-native` version to the supported version `0.65.1` and then installed the package without any problem I tried to test the project without linking and the project is not working and giving this log

```
Warning: Invalid version react-native@0.65.1 for expo sdkVersion 45.0.0. Use react-native@0.68.2
Android Bundling failed 1677ms
Unable to resolve module buffer from C:\Users\MrObscure\Desktop\react\Partner\node_modules\safe-buffer\index.js: buffer could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
  1 | /* eslint-disable node/no-deprecated-api */
> 2 | var buffer = require('buffer')
    |                       ^
  3 | var Buffer = buffer.Buffer
  4 |
  5 | // alternative to using Object.keys for old browsers
```

[linking guide](https://github.com/ViroCommunity/viro/blob/main/readmes/INSTALL_ANDROID.md)

and this is what android folder contain

[image: screenshot]